# CASE statement alternate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table which holds two country ids along with some other columns

as a sample something like

```
Table(Id int,Title varchar(250), WebCountryId int, CountryId  int)
```

Web country id 1000 is for UK and CountryId =5 is for uk. (Also countryid =1 is for unknown which consider as UK). (Two countryids are are driven from two different databases which have their own list of countries)
I have a view which uses this table and I am trying to create a field to determine whether the row is UK or not.

This is what I have at the moment, but this bit gona be used in a view

```
SELECT CountryId,WebCountryId,
        (CASE WHEN (T.WebCountryId IS NULL AND T.CountryId IS NULL) THEN 1
              WHEN (T.WebCountryId IS NOT NULL AND T.WebCountryId <> 1000) THEN 0
              WHEN (T.CountryId IS NOT NULL AND Enquiry.CountryId NOT in(1,5)) THEN 0
              WHEN (T.WebCountryId IS NULL AND T.CountryId in(2,5)) THEN 1 END)as Uk           
FROM Table T
```

Is there any other way to achieve this without using `case` ?

Comment: this is why you shouldn't give NULL an implied value, i would simply have a value for every option and NOT deal with nulls.

Comment: @TMcKeown: This is what I came across when working in a very old database where no body knows why it allows NULL :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION` and just divide logic between two sets.

```
SELECT T.CountryId
       ,T.WebCountryId
       ,0 AS Uk
    FROM Table_T AS T
    WHERE ( T.WebCountryId IS NOT NULL AND T.WebCountryId <> 1000)
        OR ( T.CountryId IS NOT NULL AND Enquiry.CountryId NOT IN ( 1, 5 ))
UNION ALL
SELECT T.CountryId
       ,T.WebCountryId
       ,1 AS Uk
    FROM Table_T AS T
    WHERE ( T.WebCountryId IS NULL AND T.CountryId IS NULL )
        OR ( T.WebCountryId IS NULL AND T.CountryId IN ( 2, 5 ))
```

Comment: Depending on indexes that you have, you should check execution plan to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I would fix the data so that your queries work with straightforward logic, if that is possible.  otherwise what you have is what you will have to live with.

Comment: In this case I am not able to change the existing structure. Thanks for the input !!